# how to extract values and then obtan averages from data set

Tags: excel, shell

Hi I have the following data set in a text file:

```
#1|30|1390683923|3000|5|00:1a:1e:87:04:d0|Nexus 4, 4.4, MAKOZ30d
$1|1390683926
?[24.32846, 1.1096518, 7.2424746]
%eaglenet|00:1a:1e:87:04:d0|-66|5785
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:87:04:42|-59|2412
%UNT|00:1a:1e:87:04:d1|-68|5785
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:87:04:d2|-66|5785
%UNT|00:1a:1e:85:a4:11|-71|5200
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:85:a4:12|-70|5200
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:87:04:c2|-70|2462
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:85:a4:02|-68|2462
%UNT|00:1a:1e:87:04:51|-71|5745
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:87:04:52|-69|5745
%eduroam|00:24:6c:c1:c1:82|-70|2437
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a2|-77|2437
%UNT|00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b1|-79|5180
%UNT|00:24:6c:c1:c1:81|-70|2437
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b2|-80|5180
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:84:92:02|-72|2437
%UNT|00:24:6c:c1:c1:91|-82|5220
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:8d:f7:b2|-86|5240
%eduroam|00:24:6c:c1:c1:92|-83|5220
%UNT|00:1a:1e:8d:f7:b1|-88|5240
%eduroam|00:1a:1e:87:03:e2|-86|2437
%eaglenet|00:1a:1e:85:a4:10|-70|5200
%|00:1a:1e:85:a4:13|-76|5200
%eaglenet|00:1a:1e:87:04:50|-69|5745
%eaglenet|00:24:6c:c1:c1:80|-69|2437
%eaglenet|00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b0|-78|5180
%|00:24:6c:c1:c1:93|-81|5220
%eaglenet|00:24:6c:c1:c1:90|-81|5220
```

what I need to do is to extract the mac adress and it's corresponding signal strength for each row.
the mac addresses are repeated in the data set, so besides extracting the Mac address and signal strength I need to get the average of the signal strengths for each mac address repeated.

any program can be used

any idea on how to achieve this?

thank you

Comment: I have tried with excel. with a formula for obtaining the average, but it is too much labor consuming since I'll need to do the average for several mac addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting the data into Excel and doing a Text To Columns action against the pasted data with a "|" character as the separator will separate your data out for you. Then you can use an AVERAGEIF formula to determine the average signal strength for each individual MAC address. That should get you started at the very least.

Here's some documentation for you:

Text To Columns: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261

AVERAGEIF function:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx

*edit*
Or, rather than doing an AVERAGEIF, you could use a Pivot Table and summarize the signal strength data in your value fields by average.

Comment: the problem is that I have a very large data set. so I need to find a way to say "when you find this mac address, consider the value to make the average, once found all mac addresses take the average and save it

Comment: A Pivot Table will be your best solution then. Try using that.